# Remove Hawaii in geopandas' naturalearth_lowres world map

Tags: python, geopandas

I am trying to remove Hawaii from a world map which already excludes most other stuff in the Pacific. It's geopandas' low-res built-in world map.

(Polynesia and Antarctica take up space / make maps look awkward for many purposes when they are not needed and when small Pacific islands are not even visible/resolved on the map).

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import geopandas as gpd

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

# Fix bugs in this dataset !!!!!
#world.loc[world['name'] == 'France', 'iso_a3'] = 'FRA'
#world.loc[world['name'] == 'Norway', 'iso_a3'] = 'NOR'
#world.loc[world['name'] == 'Somaliland', 'iso_a3'] = 'SOM'
#world.loc[world['name'] == 'Kosovo', 'iso_a3'] = 'RKS'

# Remove Antarctica
world = world[(world.pop_est>0) & (world.name!="Antarctica")]

# Remove Hawaii
# Create a custom polygon
from shapely.geometry import Polygon        
polygon = Polygon([(-175, -85), (-175, 85), (180, 85), (-175, 85), (-175, -85)])
poly_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame([1], geometry=[polygon], crs=world.crs)

world = world.clip(polygon)
```

The above is a MWE to give the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/papers/whr2022/tmptest.py in <module>
     18 poly_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame([1], geometry=[polygon], crs=world.crs)
     19 
---> 20 world = world.clip(polygon)

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    309                     stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310                 )
--> 311             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    312 
    313         return wrapper

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in clip(self, lower, upper, axis, inplace, *args, **kwargs)
  10693         **kwargs,
  10694     ) -> DataFrame | None:
> 10695         return super().clip(lower, upper, axis, inplace, *args, **kwargs)
  10696 
  10697     @deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments(version=None, allowed_args=["self", "method"])

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in clip(self, lower, upper, axis, inplace, *args, **kwargs)
   7423         result = self
   7424         if lower is not None:
-> 7425             result = result._clip_with_one_bound(
   7426                 lower, method=self.ge, axis=axis, inplace=inplace
   7427             )

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _clip_with_one_bound(self, threshold, method, axis, inplace)
   7271             threshold_inf = threshold
   7272 
-> 7273         subset = method(threshold_inf, axis=axis) | isna(self)
   7274 
   7275         # GH 40420

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py in f(self, other, axis, level)
    467         self, other = align_method_FRAME(self, other, axis, flex=True, level=level)
    468 
--> 469         new_data = self._dispatch_frame_op(other, op, axis=axis)
    470         return self._construct_result(new_data)
    471 

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _dispatch_frame_op(self, right, func, axis)
   6886             # i.e. scalar, faster than checking np.ndim(right) == 0
   6887             with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
-> 6888                 bm = self._mgr.apply(array_op, right=right)
   6889             return type(self)(bm)
   6890 

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in apply(self, f, align_keys, ignore_failures, **kwargs)
    323             try:
    324                 if callable(f):
--> 325                     applied = b.apply(f, **kwargs)
    326                 else:
    327                     applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in apply(self, func, **kwargs)
    380         """
    381         with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
--> 382             result = func(self.values, **kwargs)
    383 
    384         return self._split_op_result(result)

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py in comparison_op(left, right, op)
    285 
    286     else:
--> 287         res_values = _na_arithmetic_op(lvalues, rvalues, op, is_cmp=True)
    288 
    289     return res_values

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py in _na_arithmetic_op(left, right, op, is_cmp)
    164 
    165     try:
--> 166         result = func(left, right)
    167     except TypeError:
    168         if is_object_dtype(left) or is_object_dtype(right) and not is_cmp:

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py in evaluate(op, a, b, use_numexpr)
    237         if use_numexpr:
    238             # error: "None" not callable
--> 239             return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b)  # type: ignore[misc]
    240     return _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
    241 

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py in _evaluate_numexpr(op, op_str, a, b)
    126 
    127     if result is None:
--> 128         result = _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
    129 
    130     return result

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py in _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
     67     if _TEST_MODE:
     68         _store_test_result(False)
---> 69     return op(a, b)
     70 
     71 

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'Polygon'
> /home/meuser/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py(69)_evaluate_standard()
     67     if _TEST_MODE:
     68         _store_test_result(False)
---> 69     return op(a, b)
     70 
     71
```

UPDATE: After upgrading `geopandas` from 0.9.0 to 0.10.1, I get instead an error about invalid geometry.

Indeed,

`polygon.is_valid`  is `False`!

How should I write a valid rectangle? I got this syntax for the polygon more ore less from the docs.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. At least it works in my environment.

From the traceback it is clear that it uses pandas `clip`, not geopandas `clip`, suggesting that you are using an outdated version of geopandas. `clip` as a GeoDataFrame method has been introduced in geopandas 0.10. Earlier versions had `geopandas.clip` function only (the latest has both).

Try using the function or updating to the latest release.

```py
from shapely.geometry import box

polygon = box(-175, -85, 175, 85)
world = gpd.clip(world, polygon)
```

Comment: sic?  `gpd.__version__` says `0.9.0` ... Update .... ah. yes. 0.10 > 0.9 ! But this is not the problem it seems... I'll edit the question with an update

Comment: If I use `gpd.clip(world,polygon)` instead, I get "
TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid: Self-intersection at or near point -175 -85 at -175 -85
"  for either version .9 or .10 of geopandas

Comment: Use `box` instead of `Polygon` to make the syntax easier. I'll update the answer in a second.

Comment: Thanks. ` polygon = box(-150, -85, 175, 85)`  works to hide Hawa'i.   I am not sure what is wrong in principle with my original code, though. Is this a bug?

Comment: Your fourth coordinates should be (180, -85) not (-175, 85). Try drawing it.

Answer (score 0):

- you have not defined a valid polygon,  see below
- use corrected definition and `clip()` works

#### definition in sample code

```
Polygon([(-175, -85), (-175, 85), (180, 85), (-175, 85), (-175, -85)])
```

[image]

#### modified 4th co-ordinate

```
Polygon([(-175, -85), (-175, 85), (180, 85), (180,-85), (-175,-85)])
```

[image]